# Saving images in Chrome's Read Later Fast

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Some of you might know the Chrome plugin [Read Later Fast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/read-later-fast/decdfngdidijkdjgbknlnepdljfaepji?hl=en) which enables the user to read web pages later offline.

My problem is when a page is marked for offline read, no images from that page are downloaded. Nothing in the plugin's settings is helpful.

My question is whether it is possible to download and save images when marking a page for later read

Comment: I see... What is your question?

Comment: [Chromium scrapbook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-scrapbook/gokffdfnlmampchciemmflgbckijpmlb?hl=en) can do it, but this will not updated in future anymore. Another alternative could be [scrapbook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrapbook/fihabipakbgncingdhhdidlbhneeicne/details?hl=en).

Comment: Try the plugins I suggested you and let me know about them.